# Es posible calcular la media en la columna de disponibilidad

Tags: sql, sql-server

Me gustaria saber si es posible sumar la disponibilidad y dividirla entre el numero de equipos para obtener la media de la disponibilidad (Availability)

El Query es el siguiente :

```
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime DECLARE @EndDate DateTime
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, DATEADD(m, -1, DATEADD(d, 1 - day(getdate()), getdate()))), 0)
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(ms, -2,DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, DATEADD(d, 1 - day(getdate()), getdate())), 0));

SELECT SummaryMonth,
       NodeID,
       Vendor_Icon,
       NodeName,
       IP_Address,
       AVERAGE_of_Availability,
       SLA_Node,
       SLA,
       SLA_Status
FROM
  (SELECT TOP 100 CONVERT(DateTime, LTRIM(MONTH(DateTime)) + '/01/' + LTRIM(YEAR(DateTime)), 101) AS SummaryMonth,
              Nodes.NodeID AS NodeID,
              Nodes.VendorIcon AS Vendor_Icon,
              Nodes.Caption AS NodeName,
              Nodes.IP_Address AS IP_Address,
              AVG(ResponseTime.Availability) AS AVERAGE_of_Availability,
              Nodes.SLA_Node AS SLA_Node,
              CASE
                  WHEN AVG(ResponseTime.Availability) > Nodes.SLA_Node THEN 'CUMPLE SLA'
                  ELSE 'NO CUMPLE SLA'
              END AS SLA,
              CASE
                  WHEN AVG(ResponseTime.Availability) > Nodes.SLA_Node THEN 'Up'
                  ELSE 'Down'
              END AS SLA_Status
   FROM Nodes
   INNER JOIN ResponseTime ON (Nodes.NodeID = ResponseTime.NodeID)
   WHERE (DateTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
     AND (Nodes.Caption LIKE '%SOL%') 
     GROUP BY CONVERT(DateTime, LTRIM(MONTH(DateTime)) + '/01/' + LTRIM(YEAR(DateTime)), 101),
            Nodes.NodeID,
            Nodes.VendorIcon,
            Nodes.Caption,
            Nodes.IP_Address,
            Nodes.SLA_Node ) AS r
ORDER BY SummaryMonth ASC,
         4 ASC
```

************************Resultado*******
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Solo para estar seguros: la disponibilidad es `AVERAGE_of_Availability` y la cantidad de equipos se determina sumando los `NodeID` de tu consulta?

Comment: Si es correcto como lo describes #Patricio Moracho